# Client sending data to web server, how can the server verify the client is genuine?

Tags: c#, security, webserver

I am writing a c# program that sends json data to a django web server. It is very important that the data the client sends is accurate. My concern is that if someone knew the url and the data format (they could see this if they were monitoring their network traffic), they could construct their own application that sends false data to the web server. Also isn't it possible that my own client executable could be unpacked and modified?

How can the server check the data to verify that the client sending the data is genuine and unmodified?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). 

In practice it works somehow like that:

1. Client generates a random symmetric encryption key
2. Client encrypts the message using the created key from step 1
3. Client encrypts the symmetric key using the public key from the server
4. Client sends the encrypted message and the encrypted key to the server
5. The server can now decrypt the symmetric key with its private key and then the server uses the decrypted key to decrypt the message

I hope that you understand how it works. If not search for it on the internet. You will find a lot of information about it

Comment: One thing I don't understand is how I can prevent my encryption key from being copied? Couldn't someone unpack my application and see what the key is and then use it to properly encrypt data which is false?

Comment: Thats why you shouldnt store your encryption key in your code or in a textfile or something like that. Take a look at the answer from tylerl: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12332/where-to-store-a-key-for-encryption He describes some solutions how you could solve this problem

Comment: That looks to be about encrypting data on a server. However I am talking about a client desktop application sending data to the server, so doesn't the encryption key have to be somewhere on the client at some point at which point it can be copied?

Comment: I feel like I still have the same problem though. What would stop a malicious user from creating their own program that takes false data and generates their own encryption key etc. I get this will help the data be transmitted securely but it seems like it still won't help the server tell if the client is legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you are using https for your endpoint, you are fairly safe about data being tampered with between the client and the endpoint (since it is encrypted).

For the other part, it is possible for you client to get unpacked. I would suggest having a authentication process, and building your endpoint so that they would get access only to their own data.

Comment: I should clarify that this is for something similar to a global leader-board for a game. Users will be authenticated so they won't be able to modify other users' scores, but my concern is that a user could still potentially falsify their own score.

Comment: This may sound like a patch fix, but maybe you could time the score. Say a user can't possibly earn 1.000.000 points in a day/ hour/ minute. 
I am curious about this problem as well, can't say I know a best practice for this.

Comment: That is a good idea, I'm sure there are a lot of ways the server can detect cheating and suspicious behavior. Using this in combination with encryption and hashing like @CoLiNaDE was talking about should be a pretty good deterrent.